# AWS EMR how to use shell script as bootstrap action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I need to be able to use Java 8 in EMR I have found this post

https://crazydoc1.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/java-8-on-amazon-emr-ami-4-0-0/

Which provides a bootstrap shell script

https://gist.github.com/pstorch/c217d8324c4133a003c4

Which installs java 8.

When looking at documentation on how to use bootstrap scripts its not apparent at all how to use a shell script with bootstrap actions since in documentation it asks for a Jar location (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html)

```
Under Bootstrap Actions select Configure and add to specify the Name, JAR location, and arguments for your bootstrap action. Choose Add.
```

I don't have a Jar location I have a shell script as a bootstrap action.

[image]

How am I suppose to use a shell script should I just enter the shell script as Jar location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is add the `S3` location of your script as the `JAR location` (or just navigate to it using the form).

Example:

```
s3://mybucket/myfolder/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Correct, the JAR location mentioned in the console and docs is misnamed at time of this question.  The bootstrap action is expecting a path to a script.