# bootstrap action on AWS EMR 4.2.0

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I need to run an EMR cluster using Hadoop 2.6.5 with java 8.
The EMR corresponding with the required Hadoop version is 4.2.0 and this version runs Java 7.
from this post [AWS EMR how to use shell script as bootstrap action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121593/aws-emr-how-to-use-shell-script-as-bootstrap-action),
I know that I can run bash scripts (or not?).

I'm trying to add a bootstrap action (custom) to my cluster with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk -y
sudo yum install java-1.8.0 -y
exit 0
```

I get the following error after bootstrap on the AWS EMR console:

```
On 2 slave instances (including <some-id>), bootstrap action 2 returned a non-zero return code
```

and then the cluster is being terminated.
I searched the logs (under bootstrap-action) and I've found that my shell script did worked

```
    ===============================================================================
 Package             Arch   Version                     Repository         Size
================================================================================
Removing:
 java-1.7.0-openjdk  x86_64 1:1.7.0.99-2.6.5.0.66.amzn1 @amzn-updates      90 M
Removing for dependencies:
.
.
.

Removed:
  java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.7.0.99-2.6.5.0.66.amzn1   
.
.
.
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                     Arch   Version                  Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 java-1.8.0-openjdk          x86_64 1:1.8.0.77-0.b03.9.amzn1 amzn-updates 222 k

.
.
.
Installed:
  java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.77-0.b03.9.amzn1
.
.
.
```

I just don't understand what does the EMR looking for when it tells me

> bootstrap action 2 returned a non-zero return code

When I did give him 'exit 0'

Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd bootstrap action is startup of Hadoop, it failed because you replaced java, I guess. Maybe you can check java configuration of Hadoop, something like java_home etc.